# How to read typed text in Word add-in using requirement set 1.1

Tags: ms-word, office-js

Using the office add in API it is fairly trivial to get the text that the user is typing using Requirement Set 1.3.

However how would you do this with Requirement Set 1.1? It seems to be fairly easy to get the text of the active paragraph using `context.document.getSelection().paragraphs`- but how do you get the text that the user has just typed? Or to put it another way- how do you read from the cursor and back to the beginning of the paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the ranges methods we shipped in 1.3 to do it more precisely. Your best bet at this point (using what 1.1 provides)  is to use what you proposed: get the first paragraph (using as you suggested *getSelection().paragraphs*, obviously that will give you the entire paragraph and may not be what you expect.

In addition to the above, you can check if 1.3 is supported and suggest the user to upgrade for better experience.